# Azure Multi Container Web App stops the site apperently for no reason

Tags: mysql, spring, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to set up a Spring Boot API w/ MySQL containers in an app service. This is the docker-compose file that I'm using:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${__dc__MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_USER=${__dc__MYSQL_USERNAME}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${__dc__MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${__dc__MYSQL_DATABASE}

  thesisapi:
    image: ${__dc__IMAGE}
    container_name: thesisapi
    restart: always
    ports:
      # Azure Web App exposes port 80
      - 80:${__dc__SERVER_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=${__dc__SERVER_PORT}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/${__dc__MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=${__dc__MYSQL_USERNAME}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=${__dc__MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
      - SPRING_JPA_DATABASE_PLATFORM=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

**Note 1** I ran the above docker-compose locally and it works flawlessly.

**Note 2** When uploading the file to the App Service, there are actual values instead of variables, i.e. ${foo}.

The downloading of the images works okay. MySQL server starts and says that it waits for connections, but my app fails a couple of times until the MySQL service is ready to go. From what I saw in the ms docs, `depends_on` is ignored.

After a couple of fails, my API starts but for some reason, the App Service decides to stop the containers and retry. Then it does the same again, and again and so on... I'm already trying for a couple of days to get this working and it got on my nerves.

I also have a frontend app image that I'm uploading to an app service, but it has no dependencies to other services, and that starts and can be used.

The logs that I gathered:

```
INFO 1 --- [ task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
INFO 1 --- [ task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
ERROR 1 --- [ task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

...

WARN 1 --- [ task-1] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

...

INFO 1 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 5000 (http) with context path '/api'
INFO 1 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
INFO 1 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
INFO 1 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
INFO 1 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
INFO 1 --- [           main] my.app.MyApplication                     : Started MyApplication in 25.648 seconds (JVM running for 28.112)
INFO  - Stopping site bsdeploydev3api because it failed during startup.
```

**UPDATE**

So I gave up on having both my app and a MySQL container running and instead I created a dedicated Azure Resource for the MySQL which is called `Azure Database for MySQL server`.

After everything was set and done, my app still couldn't connect to the database and this time the issue was:

> java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Coordinated Universal Time' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

To fix this, I had to set `?serverTimezone=UTC` in the connection string. After that it was working.

Now I wonder the following things:

- When I was running the above docker-file locally I didn't run into this issue. I suppose that if the MySQL server and an app that tries to connect to it live on the same system, there is no need to set that query param.
- Could this have been the issue also with the containers being deployed to the `App Service`? Practically, they live on the same machine and I would assume that the behaviour should have been the same as locally.

So, if someone has insights into this, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [responded](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/answers/352454/view.html) to your [question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/351687/azure-web-app-multi-conainter.html?childToView=352454#answer-352454) on Q&A. The gist is `depends_on` [isn't supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#configure-multi-container-apps) on multi-container apps, it gets ignored. I suggest removing the startup dependency on your MySQL image.

Comment: If you have any insights into the last update that I did for the question, it would be great and helpful for anyone struggling with this issue.

Comment: @Vivere I would think no because the time zone `show variables like 'time_zone';` would mostly likely be set to SYSTEM. I'm not 100% certain but I think the guest os for Azure MySQL is WIndows, whereas `base mysql` is based on Debian. That's probably why you didn't get the problem before.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still looking for the answer but I have added `entrypoint` in api in the following way:

`entrypoint: ["./wait_for.sh", "db:3306", "-t", "3600", "--", "execute", "api"]`

Here `./wait_for.sh` is taken from https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

`db:3306` is the mysql database running on 3306 where my api depends

and last two parameters are the commandline to execute my api.

Following is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql
     volumes:
       - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
     environment:
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbName
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=MyRootPassword!
       - MYSQL_USER=dbUser_1
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dbUser_1sPassword!
     restart: always

   api:
     depends_on:
       - db
     entrypoint: ["./wait_for.sh", "db:3306", "-t", "3600", "--", "execute", "api"] #waiting very long enough to set the db server up and running
     image: <my registry url>/api:latest
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     restart: always

volumes:
  mysql:
        driver: azure_file
        driver_opts:
          share_name: Azure_Share_Name
          storage_account_name: Azure_Storage_Account_Name
          storageaccountkey: Azure_Key
```

Comment: This looks cool. I think I would handle the waiting inside the app, but in the future when I need synchronization that I can't handle, I will definitely use this. Thanks for sharing.